# Using a loop + string accumulator to format a List

Tags: python, string, list, format, accumulator

I created a function definition to get user input (numbers) and then store it into a list.

```
[52.0, 55.0, 567.0, 92.0, 2.0, 5.0]
```

and I'm trying to format using a loop w/ string accumulator so it'll look something like this:

```
{$52.00, $55.00, $567.00, $92.00, $2.00, $5.00}
```

all ***without*** using the .join method.
I can easily do it with the .join method, but the goal is to make it in a function definition as a loop so I can use it else where in my program.

Comment: use for each with formatted text?

Comment: I don't understand why join can't be used in a function definition.

Comment: You actually want the result to be string elements in a list like so `['$52.00', '$55.00', ...]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the motiviation in not using `join`?

```
lst = [52.0, 55.0, 567.0, 92.0, 2.0, 5.0]

def foo(lst):
    bar = ''
    for i in lst:
        i = format(i, '.2f')
        bar+= '${}, '.format(str(i))
    bar = bar.rstrip(', ')
    return '{'+bar+'}'

print(foo(lst))
```

Comment: I'm familiar with using the .join method because it just works. and very easily. I'm trying to get in the habit of knowing how each function works by making my own. Such as for min, max, and sum. which I've already done in my overall program

Comment: You learned it in a reverse order. You should learn basic stuff that builds those handy functions like `join`

Comment: That makes a good point. I guess I would say, I know what the .join will output, but I didn't know how it was doing it. Definitely going to be studying methods a lot more.